# Ubuntu wireless problem

Tags: networking

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my Toshiba L655. I have never used Linux before this, so I do not know much about it.

When I try to connect to my hidden wireless network, I put the password encryption as WPA/WPA2 PSK Personal and put my password in. It tries to connect to it for 30 seconds to one minute then I get a window that pops up saying something along the lines of (not looking at it, laptop is off charging) "this network requires password or encryption code authorization". I put the same password in that I set it to origionally. It begins doing its thing again trying to connect and a few seconds later it pops up again, and again, and again. I do not have any encryption codes or other passwords etc. What should I do?

Thanks, any suggestions will really help!

Answer (score 0):

did you set an admin password? Sometimes it asks you for that first so you might be putting your wireless username into your ubuntu admin without realizing. I should stress, that it depends on your settings. It could be something else but that is the first thing you probably should look at.

If that does not solve it, I would plug the laptop into the network with a cable and update yourself and see if that does anything for you.